# Get specific logs from SendWithUs with API

Tags: sendwithus

I was just trying to get a specific logs from SendWithUs, but cannot really find any info. Googled all around the place. API documentation on SWU does not say how to pull like "email_name" with a specific text in it. I want to pull the logs where "email_name" could be specified or at least "email_name" like '%specificemailname%'. Any ideas?

I will really appreciate every single answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to filter logs programatically. Sendwithus has two log API endpoints. One to [get information about a log](https://support.sendwithus.com/api/#getaspecificlogmetadata) using the `receipt_id` returned an a send API call. The [second lists email event information](https://support.sendwithus.com/api/#retrieveeventsforaspecificlog_id.) (opens, clicks, etc) for a given log.

Did you reach out to the support team for help?